# How to handle a object like a tree with table view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tree

I have to implement a table view, where my tree objects are shown in the beginning there are 3 roots, when I click on one root, I get to another UITableViewController, where all the children are shown. This already works perfectly. When I now click on one of the children, my table gets reloaded and the child nodes of this child are shown.

But here's my problem, I don't know how often I have to go through the nodes, to come to the end of a tree, and it should be possible to go a single step back again. It would be easy to just create multiple tableViewController, but without knowing how deep the tree is, this doesn't make sense for me...

So my question is: is there a way to copy a UITableViewController - with the same code from where the segue should be performed - programmatically, so if I click on a cell, a new UITableViewController is created with the cell's children?

Or is there an easier way?

Comment: just instantiate a new one, why would it need to be a copy?

Comment: I'm note sure if i understood what you mean. But you can use a navigation controller and then just push the new tables as a new instance. The tree depth would be the number of view controllers in navigationcontroller.viewcontrollers

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers, I'm pretty new to ios applications. @Maik639 your answer helped me, didn't know that was possible, thanks! :)